# Nginx missing content-type for woff2

Tags: nginx, mime-types, content-type, woff, woff2

The problem, nginx missing content type for woff2

```
curl -s -I -X GET https://.../Montserrat-Medium.woff2
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 10 Oct 2018 10:30:54 GMT
Content-Length: 118676
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Last-Modified: Wed, 10 Oct 2018 10:27:24 GMT
ETag: "1cf94-577dd4cdf1e25"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

What I've try:

1. added  `application/woff2 woff2;` to `/etc/nginx/mime.types` (also application/x-font-woff2, etc)
2. add to server section this part and it works

   location ~* ^.+.woff2$ {
   return 403;
   }
3. change part above to this and still have no success

```
    location ~* ^.+\.woff2$ {
        proxy_pass      https://82.202.226.111:8443;
        add_header      Content-type application/woff2;
        root            /var/web/public_shtml;
        access_log      off;
        expires         7d;
        try_files       $uri @fallback;
    }
```

Also I've view `nginx -T` configuration to be sure where is no other conditions for woff2.

Comment: If you `proxy_pass` to `82.202.226.111:8443`, it is probably that server that needs to provide the Content-Type.

Answer (score 0):

(3) is almost right. Add also the following to remove the upstream's `Content-Type`:

```
proxy_hide_header Content-Type;
```

Changes to `mime.types` file are not necessary in this case.

---

But Richard Smith is right, it's the upstream who returns the wrong content type.